# Remove duplicate entries from Table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a table like below (using MS SQL server 2008)

```
Contact1    Contact2
--------    ---------
1234567890  9087654321
9087654321  1234567890
1234567890  1234567890
9087654321  9087654321
8989898989  9898989898
9898989898  8989898989
```

The values of Contact1 and Contact2 in 2nd row and 5th row is the swapped form of the values in 1st row and 6th row respectively. Also both the values are equal in 3rd and 4th row.

As there are several bogus entries, I need to remove those. The resulting table shall look like-

```
Contact1    Contact2
--------    ---------
1234567890  9087654321
8989898989  9898989898
```

I am a beginner to SQL and not getting any idea to proceed. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: if there are duplicate entries in `Contact1` or `Contact2` across multiple rows? which one do you want to keep? the one with the lowest row number?

Comment: Yes. I want to keep the one with lowest row number.

Comment: If there's an entry where `Contact1` = `Contact2` and there's no other entry with the same Contact, should that entry be left in the table or deleted?

Comment: Thanks @AndriyM for your comment. Yes, that entry shall be present in table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have got the solution from MSDN [Forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/transactsql/thread/3d635afa-e909-46d5-92e6-49844dccd053)

```
WITH swapped_Contacts AS (
     SELECT
        CASE WHEN Contact1 <= Contact2 THEN Contact1 ELSE Contact2 END AS Contact1
        ,CASE WHEN Contact2 > Contact1 THEN Contact2 ELSE Contact1 END AS Contact2
    FROM dbo.Contacts
)
,ordered_Contacts AS (
    SELECT 
        Contact1
        , Contact2
        , ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Contact1, Contact2 ORDER BY Contact1, Contact2) AS rownum
    FROM swapped_Contacts
    )
DELETE
FROM ordered_Contacts
WHERE 
rownum > 1


DELETE Contacts
FROM   Contacts C1
WHERE  Contact1 = Contact2
AND   EXISTS (SELECT *
          FROM   Contacts C2
          WHERE  C1.Contact1 IN (C2.Contact1, C2.Contact2) 
            AND  C2.Contact1 <> C2.Contact2)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do it as follows:

1. Rename the table to contacts_old (using `sp_rename`)
2. Create contacts table.
3. Insert the records where Contact1 = Contact2 from contacts_old to contacts.
4. Delete the records where Contact1 = Contact2 from contacts_old
5. Now we are left with records where

   1. The contact records are unique without any swapping. You can identify such records by performing a `LEFT INNER JOIN` on the same table with `JOIN` condition as `c1.Contact1 = c2.Contact2 AND c1.Contact2 = c2.Contact1` with WHERE clause as `c2.Contact1 IS NULL`. Once inserted into contacts, you can delete these records.
   2. The contact columns are swapped and present. You might want to think about this on your own now that you have something to start with.

Comment: Thanks @Vikdor for your comment. I will try to proceed in this way. However, If there's an entry where Contact1 = Contact2 and there's no other entry with the same Contact, I need to keep that record (which is being deleted in step 2).

Comment: Oh!, then you would not run that step.